# Tkinter Canvas widget has no height or width attributes

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I found this list of Canvas widget attributes.: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html

At the top of the page it says "Tkinter 8.5 reference...". I import Tkinter using IDLE.
1) Tkinter.TkVersion returns 8.5
2) Tkinter.TclVersion returns 8.5

I define a Canvas widget in the code:
    surf_plot = Canvas(root,bg=ocean)

I then do:
    root.update()

In another function, I attempt to get the width and height of the canvas.
    draw_grid_lines(surf_plot)

```
def draw_grid_lines(widget):

    width = widget.width()
    height = widget.height()
```

The progam fails with:

AttributeError: Canvas instance has no attribute 'width'
AttributeError: Canvas instance has no attribute 'height'

I doublechecked the list of Canvas methods and attributes using IDLE (Netbeans won't show me those). Neither of those attributes appear.

```
from Tkinter import *

print str(TkVersion)
print str(TclVersion)

def gui_quit():
    root.quit()



def define_frames():

    ocean = '#C0C0C0'
    surf_plot = Canvas(root,bg=ocean)

    func_cmd = Frame(root,bg='gray')
    std_cmd = Frame(root,bg='gray')

    root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=2)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=2)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(2,weight=2)
    surf_plot.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,rowspan=2,sticky="nsew")
    root.update()
    draw_grid_lines(surf_plot)
    func_cmd.grid(row=0,column=3,columnspan=1,rowspan=1,sticky="nsew")
    std_cmd.grid(row=1,column=3,columnspan=1,rowspan=1,sticky="nsew")

    func_lab = Label(func_cmd,relief=RIDGE,width=40,text="Function/Unit Commands")
    std_lab = Label(std_cmd,relief=RIDGE,width=40,text="Standard Commands")

    func_lab.grid(row=0,column=0)
    std_lab.grid(row=0,column=0)


def define_global_buttons():
    print "Inside define buttons"
    root.bind_all('<KeyPress-F4>',get_out)
    root.bind_all('<KeyPress-F12>',toggle_grid_lines)
    root.grid()

def draw_grid_lines(widget):

    width = widget.width()
    height = widget.height()
    print "We need to draw grid lines on a canvas that is "+str(width)+" wide and "+str(height)+" high"

def get_out(event):
    print "We are out of here!"
    gui_quit()

def toggle_grid_lines(event):
    global grid_lines_active

    print "Inside toggle_grid_lines"
    if grid_lines_active:
        print "We are turning off grid lines"
        grid_lines_active = False
    else:
        print "We are turning on grid lines"
        grid_lines_active = True


grid_lines_active = False

root = Tk()
root.grid()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(background = 'black')
hgt = root.winfo_screenheight()
wdt = root.winfo_screenwidth()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Window height = "+str(hgt)
    print "Window width = "+str(wdt)

    define_frames()
    define_global_buttons()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `width` and `height` aren't `Canvas` object attributes, they're ***options*** which can be specified as keyword arguments you can use when creating an instance or calling an existing instance's `config()` method. If you call the `config()` method on a `Canvas` widget with no arguments, you'll get a dictionary of all it's current options. The keys are the option names. This is documented in [this section](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html).

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for forcing me to go back and re-read the nmt.edu posting. I wish I had been this literate about five hours ago...

Comment: The other question remains standing: All the SO posts I've read say to use .winfo_width and .winfo_height. These return the same values as the screensize. The code above gives me the desired layout without having to be explicit about sizing; I have been playing around trying different ways to have the rendered Canvas size returned, but no joy.

Comment: Consider closed...for now. I moved the root.update() and surf_plot.update() calls to the very bottom of the definition. So far, so good. Thanks all for the help and patience.

Comment: `winfo_width` and `winfo_height` are universal widget _methods_ which means you have to call them to get the value: i.e. `w = surf_plot.winfo_width()`. Assuming that's what you're doing, I don't really understand your comment before last.

Comment: The reason the width and height values you're getting are the same as the screensize may be because you didn't specify a them when you created the `Canvas` widget with `surf_plot = Canvas(root,bg=ocean)`, or any place else—so the results are their default values (which isn't documented anywhere that I know about).

Comment: @martineau: the reason it returns the screen size is because the code has the canvas fill the window, and the code explicitly makes the window the same size as the screen.

Comment: @Bryan: That makes a lot of sense—and as always, thank you for the insight into how tkinter works.